# Convert hexadecimal string to its numerical values in C#

Tags: c#, string, hex

i have a text box on my form. I want to write "0x31" as a string to my textbox and then when i clicked a button, i want to convert this string to 0x31 as a hexadecimal value.

How can i convert this string to hexadecimal value?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
string hexValues = "48 65 6C 6C 6F 20 57 6F 72 6C 64 21";
string[] hexValuesSplit = hexValues.Split(' ');
foreach (String hex in hexValuesSplit)
{
    // Convert the number expressed in base-16 to an integer.
    int value = Convert.ToInt32(hex, 16);
    // Get the character corresponding to the integral value.
    string stringValue = Char.ConvertFromUtf32(value);
    char charValue = (char)value;
    Console.WriteLine("hexadecimal value = {0}, int value = {1}, char value = {2} or {3}",
                    hex, value, stringValue, charValue);
}
```

Example From: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311038.aspx

Answer (score 16):

```
int i = Convert.ToInt32("0x31", 16);
Console.WriteLine("0x" + i.ToString("X2"))
```

Answer (score 5):

First to clear up: The string is in hexadecimal format, when you convert it to a value it's just a numeric value, it's not hexadecimal.

Use the `Int32.Parse` method with the `NumberStyle.HexNumber` specifier:

```
string input = "0x31";

int n;
if (input.StartsWith("0x")) {
  n = Int32.Parse(input.Substring(2), NumberStyles.HexNumber);
} else {
  n = Int32.Parse(input);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The string hex value is a representation of a value. The actual string value can be converted to whatever you like(float, int etc.) 
There are several ways to do [the conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311038.aspx). Simple example:

```
// convert to int from base 16
int value = Convert.ToInt32(hex, 16);
```

Comment: You can have two options:

 - If your Hex contains the **0x** preffix:
```csharp
Convert.ToInt32("Your Hex", 16);
```
- If your HEX doesn't contain the **0x** preffix:
```csharp
int.Parse("Your Hex", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

Answer (score 2):

Hexadecimal is just a representation of an value, it is not a value itself.

This page will tell you everything you need to know about parsing and displaying hex in C#

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311038.aspx

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20633441)

Comment: @JessedeBruijne This is FAR from a link only answer, and should not be deleted via the LQP queue.

Comment: @FrankerZ Take away the link, and what is left? Merely a comment, not an answer. OP asked on how to convert the value, which this comment does not answer. If the post contained a sample of the code provided in the link, it would be valid, but as of now, it's really a link-only answer, and even if it's not, it's certainly not "FAR from a link only answer".

Comment: Ironically, the accepted answer has the exact same link in it, but is still a valid answer if the linked page would change.

Answer (score 0):

Note that hex is just a representation of a value - so what you are really asking is how you can parse a value from the string - do it like so:

```
int val = int.Parse("0x31", NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

val now contains an int with the hex value 0x31.

Comment: This is wrong. It should be "31" without prefix "0x" or else it throws System.FormatException