# I want to convert the character variable into numerical variable

Tags: r, numeric

I have 14000 odd obs.

```
----------
shopper_id
----------
4590FBB2C98F98BF51769EB162F527D9

135BC3FBD2C32B6F2DC6BAA92EA63747

DCF1C2CD4351DF74551E7AE3A5365983

83C4D97CA2DEF71ED33DF8A8D6F8E864

AD20D56153044D0F729EFC10A3DF0F71
```

`ShopperId` is a unique ID in my dataset, I want to run apriori.

My code:

```
df_sorted <- beauty[order(beauty$shopper_id),]
df_sorted$shopper_id <-as.numeric(df_sorted$shopper_id)
```

I am getting the below error:

> ```
> Warning message:
> NAs introduced by coercion
> ```

Comment: shopper_id isn't numeric, you can't do as.numeric on it.

Comment: `as.numeric(as.factor(df_sorted$shopper_id))`

Comment: How do you expect to convert a string to number? What are you expecting to get? The numbers within the string or assign a value to each string?

Comment: Your `shopper_id` is not numeric, to be certain, nor does it seem to have any non random structure.  You should be able to just order by it directly to group shoppers together.

Comment: relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9289258/how-to-create-id-column-in-r , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35558799/r-transform-a-factor-id-variable-into-a-numeric-id-variable

Comment: is it hexadecimal value?
then use this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9820165/convert-hexadecimal-string-to-its-numerical-values-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

Use `dplyr::dense_rank`. It gives each distinct `shopper_id` a number based on its sorted order.

```
shoper_id <- c("A", "A", "B", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C")

dplyr::dense_rank(shoper_id)
#> [1] 1 1 2 1 2 2 3 3 3
```